# Query CosmosDB with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am tying to query an existing Azure CosmosDB database with NodeJS.

```
getItems: function (callback) {
    var self = this;

    var querySpec = {
        query: 'SELECT * FROM root'
    };

    self.client.queryDocuments(self.collection._self, querySpec).toArray(function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.body);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, results);
        }
    });
}
```

For some reason it is keep complaining about `Cross Partition Query`. I am not really sure what it is. Any ideas where I may find this `Partition Key` and how to set it? Also, how can I avoid this exception in the query?

Full error message: `Cross partition query is required but disabled. Please set x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition to true, specify x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey, or revise your query to avoid this exception.`

P.S. I know there are few similar questions asked already, but none of them addresses with NodeJS.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because the document collection you're querying against is a partitioned collection.

In order to query against a partitioned collection, you would either need to specify a partition against which to execute the query or specify that you want to query across partitions. BTW, former is recommended.

For cross-partition queries, you would need to specify the same in options. So your code would be:

```
getItems: function (callback) {
    var self = this;

    var querySpec = {
        query: 'SELECT * FROM root'
    };
    const options = {//Query options
      enableCrossPartitionQuery: true
    };

    self.client.queryDocuments(self.collection._self, querySpec, options).toArray(function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.body);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, results);
        }
    });
}
```

If you're querying against a single partition, you will need to specify the partition key value in the query. In this case, your `options` would look something like:

```
const options = {
  partitionKey: 'partition-key-value'
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Something really strange happens when I add `const options`. I am running it in `VS Code` debugger and adding `options` in `queryDocuments` stops the execution before it gets to `toArray` callback function. Does that make sense?

Comment: it just stop the execution without giving any `results` or `error`.

Comment: Can you try changing const keyword to var? I was using ES6.

Comment: I tried with `var` as well. It doesn't make any difference.